# Foundation 6 for sites Basic template and JavaScript files within Git workflow

Tags: javascript, git, sass, zurb-foundation-6

I installed Foundation 6 **Basic Template** with `foundation new`. All good and ready to go.

- I have a local development environment versioned with `Git`
- Foundation comes with a `.gitignore` file where its ignoring css
  folder and `bower_components` and so on:

---

```
.DS_Store   
bower_components   
node_modules    
npm-debug.log   
css
```

---

1. I understand using `foundation watch`, it will compiling `scss/app.scss` into `css/app.css`. So now I can track `css/app.css` with Git and commit it and push it to the staging server. Is this correct?
2. But what about e.g `bower_components` folder with necessary JavaScript files. With the **Basic Template** I'm not compiling any JavaScript, is it? I want to start with a simple template and expand it and build it out if necessary. And track it with Git if possible so I can pull my changes into the staging server. How do I have to use the JavaScript files in my workflow and which JavaScript files to start with a simple template and able to version it with Git?